# How Do I Stop a Delayed Task on Appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I launched a task using the delayed package

The only problem is that the task is failing (ooops!) and is keeping trying it again and again. I am aware of the `RetryCount` field but I would like to force kill the task myself.

Does anyone knows a way to do it ?

Comment: you can do it in the admin interface IIRC.

Comment: for named queues I can but looks like that the delayed queue is hidden from the admin

Comment: I recall there being similar questions on the GAE mailing list on Google Groups.  Check there.

Answer (score 1):

The below samples from the App Engine docs would indicate that all your delay tasks created via `delay.Function#Call` should go to the `default` queue, and thus be deletable via the admin interface. If not, I would call it bug.

In fact, our delay tasks went to the `default` queue, and we could delete them with the admin interface.

#### https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/delay#Function.Call

> func (f *Function) Call(c appengine.Context, args ...interface{})

Call invokes a delayed function.

> f.Call(c, ...)

is equivalent to

> t, _ := f.Task(...)
>   taskqueue.Add(c, t, "")

#### https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/reference#Add

> func Add(c appengine.Context, task *Task, queueName string) (*Task, error)

Add adds the task to a named queue. An empty queue name means that the default queue will be used. Add returns an equivalent Task with defaults filled in, including setting the task's Name field to the chosen name if the original was empty.